# How to separate array processing into goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a slice of 30'000 strings. How do I separate processing this slice into, say, 10 goroutines that would take 3000 strings from the slice, extract some data from them and push into a new slice?

So, in the end, I will have 10 slices with 3000 processed results in each. What's the pattern to handle this problem?

I have had a look at [this article](http://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/), but not sure which of these patterns applies to my case.

Comment: Why not just have 10 goroutines and have them process strings as fast as they can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a channel, read the elements from the slice, use a Fan out to distribute load and pass messages. Then, process the strings in goroutines and collect the results back (fan in ) in a single goroutine to avoid mutexes.

You may want to set the number of Max concurrent concurrent goroutines.

Keep in mind that slices are not thread safe when writing to them.

Useful info:

> https://blog.golang.org/pipelines
>   https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#1
>   https://blog.golang.org/advanced-go-concurrency-patterns
>   https://talks.golang.org/2013/advconc.slide#1

Comment: Slices are, however, thread safe if they are used read only. His question specifically states he is reading this slice and writing to a different one. As long as the results are separate slices that are combined at the end, reading from the input is OK to do concurrently.

Comment: Ya, use a fan-in to collect the results so only a single goroutine is writing to the destination slice.  Avoids the need for a mutex.

Comment: Thanks @Kaedys. I've also added your comment to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JimB in that why limit the go routines.  However since that's your inquiry I'd maybe so something like this.. If you really want to have each gorountine do 3000 items, then it might be easier to create a 2d slice. [[3000 items],[3000 items],..] then have 1 go routine process per index in that 2d array. Otherwise below just limits the gorountines to 10.
**METHOD 1**
    package main

```
import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var s []string

// genetate some mock data
func init() {
    s = make([]string, 30000)
    n := 5
    for i := 0; i < 30000; i++ {
        b := make([]byte, n)
        if _, err := rand.Read(b); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        s[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%X", b)
    }
}

func main() {
    // set the number of workers
    ch := make(chan string)
    var mut sync.Mutex
    counter := 0

    // limit the number of gorountines to 10
    for w := 0; w < 10; w++ {
        go func(ch chan string, mut *sync.Mutex) {
            for {
                // get and update counter using mux to stop race condtions
                mut.Lock()
                i := counter
                counter++
                mut.Unlock()
                // break the loop
                if counter > len(s) {
                    return
                }
                // get string
                myString := s[i]
                // to some work then pass to channel
                ch <- myString

            }
        }(ch, &mut)
    }
    // adding time.  If you play wiht the number of gorountines youll see how changing the number above can efficiency 
    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        result := <-ch
        log.Println(time.Since(t), result, i)
    }
}
```

**METHOD2** the init function is creating a 2d array chunked out into 10 arrays each containing 3000 elements.. if you parse your data that way the logic below that needs very little modification to work

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "sync"
)

var chunkedSlice [10][3000]string

// genetate some mock data
// 2d array, each chunk has 3000 items in it
// there are 10 chunks, 1 go rountine per chunk
func init() {
    n := 5
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 3000; j++ {
            b := make([]byte, n)
            if _, err := rand.Read(b); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            chunkedSlice[i][j] = fmt.Sprintf("%X", b)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    // channel to send parsed data to

    ch := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // 10 chunks
    for _, chunk := range chunkedSlice {
        wg.Add(1)
        // if defining the 2d array e.g [10][3000]string, you need to pass it as a pointer to avoid stack error
        go func(ch chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, chunk *[3000]string) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for i := 0; i < len(chunk); i++ {
                str := chunk[i]
                // fmt.Println(str)
                // parse the data (emulating)
                parsedData := str
                // send parsed data to the channel
                ch <- parsedData
            }
        }(ch, &wg, &chunk)
    }
    // wait for all the routines to finish and close the channel
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    var counter int // adding to check that the right number of items was parsed
    // get the data from the channel
    for res := range ch {
        log.Println(res, counter)
        counter++
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to just subslice the input list into `w` subslices and process each, instead of mucking with a goroutine.  Or use a fan-out input channel in addition to a fan-in output channel.

Comment: I agree didnt think of it

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library [parapipe](https://github.com/nazar256/parapipe) to solve such task. Just slice your slice into 10 parts and send them to Pipeline, which will process them concurrently:

```
import "github.com/nazar256/parapipe"
//...
var longStringSlice []string
// ...
pipeline := parapipe.NewPipeline(10).
    Pipe(func(msg interface{}) interface{} {
    slicePart := msg.([]string)
    // process here to result
    return result
})
// chop the slice and stream parts
chopSize := int(math.Ceil(float64(len(longStringSlice)) / 10))
for i:=0;i<10;i++ {
    firstIdx := i * chopSize
    lastIdx := (i+1) * chopSize
    if lastIdx > len(longStringSlice) {
        lastIdx = len(longStringSlice)
    }
    pipeline.In() <- longStringSlice[firstIdx:lastIdx]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem handling different memory addresses in different goroutines. If your read and write actions do not overshadow the chunks, that you can simply work with ranges in massif.
https://play.golang.org/p/MU5njoNmIf7